# Arrange items in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have following problem:

[image: arrange items in WPF]
My TextBox should fill the entire space, but the property "VerticalAlignment="Stretch"" does not do this for me.

Here is my code:

```
<TextBox
x:Name="txt_in_ct_length_aisle"
Text="{Binding CtLengthAisle, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
      ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
      Validation.Error="MainViewHasErrors"
      TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
      KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0"/>
<Label x:Uid="LabelShowHint" Content="?" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

How should I set the properties right?
To sum up, I want my TextBox to fill the space until the "?" on the right side.

Can anyone of you please help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a grid that has both controls, and control it using the Columns property.

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" 
             x:Name="txt_in_ct_length_aisle"
             Text="{Binding CtLengthAisle, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
             ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
             Validation.Error="MainViewHasErrors"
             TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="1"
           x:Uid="LabelShowHint" Content="?" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
This worked perfect.

Comment: @DevKnight, if it did, can you mark the answer, so if anyone needs help, will know that it worked?